# get_file_contents too many connections

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble with this code. It is supposed to get the country code of the visitor.

```
$ipot = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ipot}"));

echo 'Your country region code is '.$details->country.'';
```

and I get this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io/173.245.48.118): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests in

Comment: You're getting a 429 error from ipinfo.io - from the message returned, it looks like they're blocking your site because you're making too many queries.

Comment: any idea how to solved it?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your server is getting banned for making too many/frequent requests to ipinfo.io

.. may i suggest an alternative approach?
download the Ipv4ToCountry.csv file from http://software77.net/geo-ip/ (or alternatively an outdated version from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/divinity76/http_log_parser/master/Ipv4ToCountry.csv ) ,

and get the country with this code? requires pdo sqlite3;

```
function ipv4_to_country_v2($ipv4){
    static $ip=false;
    $ipv4=filter_var($ipv4,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,array('flags'=>FILTER_FLAG_IPV4,'options'=>array('default'=>false)));
    if($ipv4===false){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('input is NOT a valid ipv4 address.. (sorry, no ipv6 support yet.)');
    }
    //$ip=ip2long($ipv4);
    $ip=ipv4touint($ipv4);
    if($ip===false){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('input passed FILTER_FLAG_IPV4, but ip2long could not convert it! should never happen...');
    }
    static $ipdb=false;
    static $stm=false;
    if($ipdb===false){
        $ipdb=call_user_func(function(){
            $ipdb=new PDO('sqlite::memory:','','',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
            $ipdb->query('CREATE TABLE `ipranges` (`iprange_start` INTEGER UNIQUE,`iprange_end` INTEGER UNIQUE,`country` VARCHAR(255));');
            assert(is_readable('Ipv4ToCountry.csv'));
            $iplist_raw=file_get_contents('Ipv4ToCountry.csv');
            $matches=array();
            $rex_ret=preg_match_all('/\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\,\\"([^\\"]*)\\"/',$iplist_raw,$matches);
            assert($rex_ret>9001);
            unset($matches[0],$iplist_raw);
            $iplist=array();
            //var_dump($rex_ret,$matches);
            $ipdb->beginTransaction();
            $stm=$ipdb->prepare('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `ipranges` (`iprange_start`,`iprange_end`,`country`) VALUES(:iprange_start,:iprange_end,:country);');
            $stm->bindParam(':iprange_start', $ins_iprange_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindParam(':iprange_end', $ins_iprange_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindParam(':country', $ins_country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            for($i=0;$i<$rex_ret;++$i){
                //$tmparr=array();
                # IP FROM      IP TO        REGISTRY  ASSIGNED   CTRY CNTRY COUNTRY
                # "1346797568","1346801663","ripencc","20010601","il","isr","Israel"
                //$tmparr['HHB_IPRANGE_START']=(int)$matches[1][$i];
                //$tmparr['HHB_IPRANGE_END']=(int)$matches[2][$i];
                //$tmparr['registry']=$matches[3][$i];
                //$tmparr['assigned']=$matches[4][$i];
                //$tmparr['ctry']=$matches[5][$i];
                //$tmparr['cntry']=$matches[6][$i];
                //$tmparr['HHB_COUNTRY']=$matches[7][$i];
                //$iplist[]=$tmparr;
                $ins_iprange_start=$matches[1][$i];
                $ins_iprange_end=$matches[2][$i];
                $ins_country=$matches[7][$i];
                //var_dump('adding: ',$ins_iprange_start,$ins_iprange_end,$ins_country);
                $stm->execute();
            }
            $ipdb->commit();
            return $ipdb;
        });
        $stm=$ipdb->prepare('SELECT `country` FROM `ipranges` WHERE :ip >= `iprange_start` AND :ip <= `iprange_end` LIMIT 1');
        //$stm->bindParam(':ip',$ip,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindParam(':ip',$ip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stm->execute();
    if(false!==($row=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        return $row['country'];
    }
    return 'unknown_country';
}
function ipv4touint($ipv4){
    return sprintf('%u',ip2long($ipv4));
}
```

and if the code runs too slow for you, save the database instead of recreating it in-memory every php restart  (the code above were written for a project where ipv4_to_country_v2 would be called hundreds of thousands, or millions of times, per run and the static creation of the database didn't really make much of a difference)

edit: added ipv4touint